I have an error when I install the LlamaIndex.TS
pnpm install llamaindex
WARN  1 deprecated subdependencies found: fs-promise@2.0.3 
Already up to date Progress: resolved 787, reused 778, downloaded 0, added 0, done  WARN  Issues with peer dependencies found . 
└─┬ llamaindex0.3.14   
  └─┬ chromadb 1.7.3
    └── ✕ unmet peer @google/g`enter code here`enerative-ai@^0.1.1: found 0.11.4 in llamaindex

Done in 12.7s

how to solve this issue?
please help me!
According to the LlamaIndex.ts turoial, I followed the instructions but this docs couldn't solve the my issue.
